# How to delete a word and everything that follows using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

| County |
| --- |
| Davis County |
| Ark County |
| Clay County Party |

I want to delete County and everything that proceeds County from the County column. This is what I have tried so far.

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace([r' County [a-z]*'], '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Match everything after County `r' County.*'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.` in place of `[a-z]` to match all characters or you can use `[a-zA-Z ]` to match only letters and spaces.

See [Mozilla regex reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet).